Convergence of MLE for non-IID data
Consider calculating optimal model parameter $\theta$ using MLE for the following 2 cases:

Data generating process is independent but non identical:

$L(y;\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} f_{i}(y_i;\theta)$.

Data generating process has sequential dependence and could be non-stationary:

$L(y;\theta) = \prod_{i=2}^{n} f_{i}(y_i|y_{i-};\theta) f_{1}(y_1)$.
The subscript $i$ is to indicate that the distribution of each term $f$ could be distinct. If the model is well specified, would MLE converge for 1. and 2.? Are there any proofs for convergence (or lack of) for 1. and 2. ?

Model (2) is far too general to permit any conclusions to be made.  Do you have a specific model in mind?

@whuber specifically thinking of transition densities of stochastic differential equations ex. GBM or OU processes.

It will depend, but there are some things that can usefully be said, especially if this is a smooth parametric model (as seems to be implied)
If you have a law of large numbers and central limit theorem for $\log f_i$ and the usual smoothness assumptions, then the classical proofs of consistency and asymptotic normality transfer over if you just swap out the existing LLN and CLT for a new one.
There are lots of non-independent CLTs out there, eg

$\log f_i-E\,[\log f_i|\text{history}]$ is a martingale or a local martingale
mixing conditions on $y$ as a stochastic process
mixing conditions on $y$ as a random field
'sparse' correlation conditions (Stein's method for the CLT, "graph-structured dependence" is a useful keyword)

Sadly, there is a tendency for the more complicated CLTs to be stated for identically distributed $y_i$ (eg, stationary sequences) because probabilists want to separate the interesting complications from dependence and the boring complications from differing distributions.
However, it is typically the case that (as for independent sequences) tail conditions plus conditions that all the terms are very roughly the same size will get you from identical distributions to non-identical distributions.
In the setting of time series there are some results under "long-range dependence" that don't just come from the classical proofs.

I had a question. Would IID error ($y_{data} - y_{model}$) distribution for both cases in the question be a sufficient condition for convergence?

No, it's not sufficient: you need at least one finite moment for $\log f_i$ to get convergence of the loglikelihood, and at least a little bit of uniformity in $\theta$ for the convergence to translate into consistency of $\hat\theta$

Makes sense. The $\log(f_i)$ in the comment above refers to both cases in the question right?

yes, it will be the marginal or conditional moments as appropriate

Had another question by “swap out the existing” you mean instead of checking for LLN/CLT on the DGP $Y_i$ one should check it on $\log f_i$ right?

No. Well, yes, but what I meant was that you need a version of the LLN and CLT that handle whatever sort of dependence you have.  For LLN that's usually easy; it can be a bit harder to find for the CLT

Would really appreciate if you could share any reading material that you think will be helpful to understand your answer further. Specifically the bits on swapping out the CLT/LLN and the roughly same term size and tail conditions bit. Thank you.

I specifically want to read up more on "ail conditions plus conditions that all the terms are very roughly the same size will get you from identical distributions to non-identical distributions." - intuitively this makes sense as this means that the model is fitting the DGP, however, is there any formal reading that you can recommend on this?
